# Как настроить "File --> Open Recent" чтобы второй проект открывался в новом окне?

Tags: intellij-idea, настройки

У меня после "File --> Open Recent --> щелчок мышой на выбранном проекте из списка", выбранный проект открывается в этом же самом окне IDEA и заменяет тот что был открыт.
Как настроить IDEA чтобы можно было иметь оба проекта одновременно открытыми в разных окнах?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 2):

**File** -> **Settings/Preferences** -> **Appearance & Behavior** -> **System Settings** -> **Project Opening** -> Выбрать **Open project in new window**